# Real World Cross Validation Problem

Tags: regression, cross-validation

**Hello**,

first of all I've got to confess that I'm not a statistician and therefore wouldn't mind if an answer is a bit more explicit than it usually would be among statisticians.

### The Context

To predict energies of arbitrary patterns of a certain physical system, I settled to use the MAPS code (as it is described in detail in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0201511v2.pdf)).

This code iteratively constructs a data set of *known energies* $E_i$, which provide the *dependent variable*. Those should be explained by the *independent variables*, given by the so called "correlations" $\langle \prod_{j \in \alpha^\prime}\sigma_j \rangle_{\alpha^\prime}$ (which are $\in \left[-1,1\right]$) averaged over all "clusters" $\alpha^\prime$ which are symmetrically equivalent to a specific cluster $\alpha$ included in a specific truncation. The set of all "clusters" $\alpha$ included in the cluster expansion define the truncation by limiting $\sum_\alpha$. That way, each energy of a structure described completely by $\vec{\sigma}_i$ contributes a row to the problem as per
$$
E_i = E\left\lbrace\vec{\sigma}_i\right\rbrace = \sum\limits_\alpha J_\alpha m_\alpha \langle \prod_{j \in \alpha^\prime}\sigma_j \rangle_{\alpha^\prime},
$$
such that $J_\alpha m_\alpha$ is the set of *regression coefficients*.

As the aforementioned paper describes, to prevent overfitting to our finite set of known energies, (a weighted version of) the cross validation score as given by
$$
CV^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{E_i - \hat E_i}{1-X_{i\cdot}\left(X^TX\right)^{-1}X_{i\cdot}^T}\right)^2
$$
is calculated/minimized to measure/maximize the prediction power of the truncation. Here, $\hat E_i$ is the estimation of $E_i$ using a specific truncation, and $X$ the $n\times c$ regression matrix for $n$ known energies/structures (rows) and their $c$ "correlations"/clusters (columns).

### The Problem

However, iteratively adding structures and testing truncations leads to a system that suspiciously often (as in "the vast majority of tested truncations") yields $CV^2 \rightarrow \infty$ becaucse $X_{i\cdot}\left(X^TX\right)^{-1}X_{i\cdot}^T \rightarrow 1$ in contributions from several different structures i.

In some sense, $X$ seems to become "orthogonal" at some point in the sense that $X^TX = \lVert X_{i\cdot} \rVert^2\cdot\mathbb{1}$ but I fail to make real sense of that currently.

### The Question(s)

Now, I assume the predictive power of a given truncation isn't estimated in a useful way by such a diverged CV score and I suspect there is a deeper, statistical reason for this to happen so often. Therefore I'd like to ask:

- Does such a divergent CV score signal something statistically important and, if so, what would that be?
- Is there another way to access the predictive power of a truncation aside from the CV score?

---

Please find a problematic regression matrix $X \in \left[-1,1\right]^{71\times 15}$ and the corresponding dependent variable vector $\vec{E} \in \mathbb{R}^{71\times 1}$ [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b2e7151e8e59edc43107).

In case there are any additional information of interest missing in the post above, please don't hesitate to ask me - I'll gladly provide them then.

Thank you very much in advance!